# Retrieve value from ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have added some values to `drawPoints[][]` and then made an `ArrayList` Object points that is

```
ArrayList points=new ArrayList();
points.add(drawPoints);
```

Now i want to retrieve the value of drawPoints from points, how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access first `drawPoints` in your ArrayList with

```
int[][] tmp = (int[][]) points.get(0);
```

and then you will be able to get values with for example

```
tmp[0][1];
```

Here's a little example of a program that prints values of two 2D arrays that are stored in an ArrayList:

```
int[][] drawPoints = new int[2][2];
int[][] drawPoints2 = new int[2][2];
drawPoints[0][0] = 1;
drawPoints[0][1] = 2;
drawPoints[1][0] = 3;
drawPoints[1][1] = 4;
drawPoints2[0][0] = 5;
drawPoints2[0][1] = 6;
drawPoints2[1][0] = 7;
drawPoints2[1][1] = 8;
ArrayList<Object> points=new ArrayList<Object>();
points.add(drawPoints);
points.add(drawPoints2);

for(Object tab : points){
    int[][] tmp = (int[][]) tab;
    for(int i=0;i < tmp.length;i++){ 
        for(int j=0;j<tmp[i].length;j++){ 
            System.out.println(tmp[i][j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("------------");
}
```

Comment: do i need to do something like this?
<code>for(int i=0;i<points.size();i++){
                    for(int j=0;j<points.size();j++){
                        tmp[i][j]=(int[][])points.get(i);
                    }
</code>
???

Comment: @user1167744 what are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: @user1167744 see my edit, i stored two 2D arrays in an ArrayList, then I extract each tab, put in a `tmp` variable and print their values.

Answer (score 3):

You just put a 2d array into the first slot of an ArrayList. So you'd write:

```
 int[][]somePoints = (int[][])points.get(0);
```

Comment: do i need to do some thing like this?    for(int i=0;i<points.size();i++){ for(int j=0;j<points.size();j++){ tmp[i][j]=(int[][])points.get(i); }  ??

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly:

```
points.get(0); // get the first item (at index 0) from the list
```

Comment: wow you guys are quick, 3 comments while i was editing it ;) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`points.get(i)` gives you the value, in this case `i = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` is backed by a 1-dimensional array. If you want to mimic your `drawPoints[][]`, I suggest using a `ArrayList`, then iterating over it to fill it, then retrieve the values.